# Different download tools result in different MP3 checksums

Tags: http, wget, mp3, curl, checksum

I wrote some code for downloading podcasts and noticed that the checksums of files I downloaded with it didn't match those of files downloaded using other methods.

Initially I thought there was a bug in my code but through testing I've noticed that files downloaded using wget, curl and Invoke-WebRequest also differ from each other. I've tested on my Windows 10 PC and an Ubuntu 16.04 VPS I have and the same thing happens on both.

Does anybody have any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to the website delivering slightly different streams to each downloader.
The difference could be due to watermarks (in case of copyrighted material often used to unique identify each download), DRM, different codecs used for encoding the audio stream, different meta-data (e.g timestamps like "downloaded on date/time") embedded in the file, etc.

Comment: If I download the same file multiple times using wget they all have the same checksum. If I use curl multiple times, they also have the same checksum but it's different to the wget checksum. Any ideas?

Comment: It contains the user-agent in the download? As wget isn't curl, the useragent would be different....

Comment: @djsmiley2k That's what I'm thinking too. The category "different meta-data" that I already mentioned.

Comment: Using ffprobe to inspect the metadata, the only difference I can find is that the wget files are showing a different duration than the curl ones (00:29:00.72 vs 00:28:02.16). Very strange.